# Malware has corrupted SD card

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sd-card, malware

I have android phone with SD card. Malware has moved all files to other folder. Then I copied it to previous place. But now it doesn't show applications placed in menu. It shows it in settings. What to do? How does android application in SD card must be placed?

Comment: Could you give a few more details on what has been moved from where (path) to where (path) on your SDCard? A screenshot of the misplaced applications might also prove helpful for understanding.

Comment: You should probably remove the malware first before you do anything, you can download some antivirus from the android marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Connect your SD card to your PC and execute one of the 2 programs you prefer to recover your data:

http://www.recovermyfiles.com/data-recovery-software-download.php

http://www.piriform.com/recuva